# Increasing the load capacity of this circuit

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, relay

Is there's a way to further increase the load capacity of this circuit created using Multisim Live? (I think it's what they call a relay switch circuit.)

[image]

P.S. The only thing that I 'changed' is the value of the burnout voltage of the 24 V/10 W lamp; I set it at nearly 1 kV so that the lamp won't get blown out.

Comment: That relay symbol is very nonstandard. You haven’t explained what this limit is you run in to. Is it the resistance of the contacts?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing on the coil side (left) of the relay is imposing any limits to what you can do on the switch side.

What you can do on the switch side depends on the limits of every element on that side, namely the relay switching contacts, the voltage source, and the lamp itself.

Assuming the voltage source is capable of providing any current you need from it, (or in other words, the lamp or any other load doesn't exceed that source's abilities), then your only concern is the relay's contacts.

You must consider three things:

1. Maximum switch voltage. The contacts must never be exposed to voltages greater than those specified for AC or DC, because of the potential for damage due to arcing. Different relays have different tolerances.
2. Maximum switch contact current. All relays are rated for a certain maximum DC current, and a maximum AC current. Excessive current causes heating of the contacts (because they are not perfect zero-ohm paths)
3. Related to (1) above, if the load is inductive (such as a motor), potential difference between the contacts (as they open) can exceed the relay's specifications, and the subsequent arcing can damage its contacts. For inductive loads, usually some kind of [snubber](https://makingcircuits.com/blog/snubber-circuits-for-protecting-relay-contacts-from-arcing/) circuit is necessary to suppress those voltage spikes. Some relays have snubbers built in.

The maximum load you can connect is therefore dependent on the relay you choose, and the snubber you employ (if one is needed). The answer to your question is "use an appropriate relay".

Answer (score 0):

The relay coil is shown as 1 ohm (which is highly unlikely), so 12V would be a current of 12A. The transistor has a gain of 100, so it needs 120 mA base current, so R2 would need to be 100 ohms or less.